# Using LIKE in ms sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

**Question: When I use the LIKE in my query it is gray and my query does not return anything when I know if should.**

I am not sure if there is a configuration setting I am missing but normally when I use MS sql server management studio terms like: UPDATE WHERE SELECT ADD all show as blue in my query window.

Example query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [MainSiteDB].[dbo].[usr_user]
  WHERE [MainSiteDB].[dbo].[usr_user].[usr_lastLogin] LIKE '2014-11-10%'
```

In my table in that field there are many entries like: `2014-11-10 13:19:46.967`

Comment: There must be no issue with LIKE operator. As you are using like with date, hence no result. Try to cast the date part or try other than date field to check if LIKE is working or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Like is not applicable for datetime or date field for SQL server. 'Like' is for varchar/char/text and other text related field

You can use between or <> sign

```
Select * from tblTable where Date between '2014 Jan 01' and '2014 Jan 31'
```

OR

```
Select * from tblTable where Date >= '2014 Jan 01' and Date <= '2014 Jan 31'
```

Comment: Could you recommend a different approach to solve my task above? +1

Comment: Always write dates in a way that works independent of server settings. i.e. 'yyyyMMdd' `WHERE [Date] >= '20141110' AND [Date] < '20141111'`

Answer (score 1):

> You can find in menu in Management studio menu under Tools->Option
>   then Fonts and color. Then you can change the customize color for
>   SQL keywords.

Answer (score 1):

you Can Use it :

SELECT *
  FROM [MainSiteDB].[dbo].[usr_user] 
  WHERE DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [MainSiteDB].[dbo].[usr_user].[usr_lastLogin]))= '2014-05-9'

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. Using **LIKE** directly in DateTime filed is won't give expected result. **Convert the DateTime field to specific format** to Varchar and use **LIKE**.

101 - Format the DateTime to mm/dd/yyy

```
SELECT *
  FROM [MainSiteDB].[dbo].[usr_user]
  WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), [MainSiteDB].[dbo].[usr_user].[usr_lastLogin], 101) 
  LIKE '05/22/2014%'
```

105 - Format the DateTime to mm-dd-yyy

```
SELECT *
  FROM [MainSiteDB].[dbo].[usr_user]
  WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), [MainSiteDB].[dbo].[usr_user].[usr_lastLogin], 105) 
  LIKE '05-22-2014%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the date part and then use the LIKE operator. Check the below script:

```
Select * from TableName Where colName like Cast('2014-09-25' as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tablename
where CONVERT(varchar(10), getdate(), 105) = @inputdate
```

Below convert will fetch the datepart alone from your columnname, and then based on your input it will fetch all matching records.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), getdate(), 105) -->  11-11-2014
```